# How to return the value received from a stream in Flutter/Dart instantly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stream which emits a value.

Sometimes the value is returned after 5 seconds, sometimes after 10 seconds, sometimes instantly, sometimes never.

Currently I am using a delay of 20 seconds. After this period, I stop listening to the stream and manually return the value.
However, this is highly inefficient since user have to wait for the whole 20 seconds even if the value is emitted by the stream instantly.

So, I am looking for some ways to return the value received from a stream the moment it emits a particular value.

Current code looks like this,

```
String? result;
controller.stream.listen((String data) {
  print(data);
  result = data;
});
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 20));
return result;
```

Please note that the above stream may not close after emitting the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using a `Completer`:

```
Completer<String?> completer = Completer<String?>();

controller.stream.listen((String data) {
  print(data);
  completer.complete(data);
}, onError: (dynamic error) {
  completer.completeError("Error occurred!);
});

return completer.future;
```

This approach ensures that the result is returned as soon as it's emitted by the stream, without waiting for a fixed amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Stream.timeout()`](https://api.dart.dev/be/180361/dart-async/Stream/timeout.html) to do that:

```
return controller.stream.timeout(
  Duration(seconds: 20),
  (sink) => sink.add(null),
).first;
```

This code returns a `Future` that either completes with the first event in your stream, or `null` in case of a time out.

The `timeout()` method creates a new stream that calls the closure if no data is emitted after the timeout expires.

The `first` property returns a `Future` that completes with the first event emitted by the stream. This will either be an event addet to the `controller` or `null` in case of a time out.